# Which distribution to choose while downloading Skype from its official site for Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: skype, software-installation

There is download link for Skype for Ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04. I can't find appropriate version for 13.10.

I tried from terminal to instal too:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

But it says unable to locate package skype.

And for those who are in hurry to mention this question as possible duplicate,
read this properly: I want proper download of latest Skype version for Ubuntu 13.10. It's "13.10".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These worked for me:

1. [Download](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64) Skype for **Ubuntu 32-bit Precise i386** (it does not matter if your system is on 64-bit).
2. When the download has finished, open the downloaded file as normal from Nautilus.
3. When prompted, select **Open with Ubuntu Software Center** (default).
4. In the right side of the **Ubuntu Software Center** window that opens, select **Install**.
5. Just in case that the step 4 doesn't work, try from terminal:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --force-depends -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
   ```

   Note that this step 5 is not ideal, but I'm almost sure that this will work.

**Source**: [Getting started with Skype for Linux](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12120/getting-started-with-skype-for-linux).

The command `sudo apt-get install skype` didn't worked for you because first you must to add some partner repositories to your sources list. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/287732/147044) in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the partner software sources to get it working.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy partner' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install skype
```

This should help you with your next issue :D 
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html?m=1

Comment: The OP asked: "*Which distribution to choose while downloading skype **from it's official site** for Ubuntu 13.10?*"

Comment: The post has been modified from what it originally stated so I don't know for sure, but reading between the lines it sounded to me like he was just trying to get Skype working and this method lets the asker stay up to date with the repos.

Answer (score 2):

To install Skype, the only version is Precise 12.04 (multiarch). I wouldn't recommend `--force-depends` as Radu's answer but the use of Gdebi:

```
wget http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

It will install the dependencies automatically and you will be assured that everything will be fine.

[image]

[image]

(note that the `wget` command can change if new versions of Skype are released for Linux, you can always go to the [Downloads Page](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64))

Comment: USC/apt does the almost same as `gdebi`. And what is the reason of those annoying captures from terminal?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu USC (or more accurately aptdaemon) is bad managing the whole i386/amd64 dependencies. I really do not use it. `apt` doesn't resolve dependencies if the package is not downloaded from repositories (you can see several broken dependencies questions where `apt-get -f install` didn't help). The screenshots were just... I don't know... wanted to post some screenshots.